# Файлы на сервере в корне сайта

Tags: веб-сервер, оптимизация-сайтов

Заинтересовал вопрос, какие файлы могут находиться на сервере в корне сайта, помимо файлов самого сайта.

Знаю о следующих:

- robots.txt
- meta.txt (о нем узнал [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/113910/))
- *.htaccess* - (зависит от сервера)
- sitemap.xml
- favicon.ico (может быть и не `ico` и сейчас может находится где угодно)
- err404.html (указывается в `.htaccess`, но думаю его можно включить в этот список)

А какие еще файлы, если их можно назвать "служебными" есть?

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретных сайтов и конкретных веб-серверов

Comment: Если говорить именно о «служебности» файлов, то .htaccess, sitemap.xml и err404.html вполне могут быть неслужебными и ничего не делающими, так что даже приведённый в вопросе список уже можно считать некорректным

Comment: @andreymal Согласен, тут список скорее, для примера что имел ввиду

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сама формулировка вопроса не позволяет ответить на ваш вопрос. То какие файлы есть на сервере может зависить от:

- **веб-сервера** (*apache, nginx*)
- **интерпретатора** языка программирования, если есть. (*php, nodejs, go, python*...)
- **фреймфорка** , если исходный кода сайта написан на каком то языке программирования с использование специальных бибилиотек, облегчающих промышленную разработку веб-систем (*laravel, symfony, exspress ...*)
- **cms** , системы управления сайтом (*wordpress, joomla, drupal ....*)
- и так далее.

---

каждый раз при выборе технологического стека разработки и его реализации набор файлов и библиотек будет разный. И все таки, в общем случае можно представить файлы сайта на сервере так:

- **img** - папка с изображениями
- **js** - скрипты сайта
- **css** - файлы со стилями сайта
- **index.html** - главная сайта
- **about.html** - страница о компании
- **robots.txt** - файл для поисковых систем
- **sitemap.xml** - карта сайта для поисковых систем

также необходимо понимать, что файлы на сервере, это как бы последний этап. Существует сам проект. Это в случае если проект разрабатывается с использованием языка программирования, там набор папок и файлов совершенно другой, так называемая среда разработки.

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. К серверу относиться из списка файл `.htaccess`, но вот остальные, допустим файл для поисковых систем `robots.txt` не будет зависеть от конфигурации сервера и проекта, а вот его наполнение да, о таких файлах и задумался какие еще есть

Comment: все какие есть привел в ответе, это общепринято, на практике может быть что угодно